# Scaling covariates in regularized regression with date covariate

Tags: regression, logistic, lasso, regularization

I'm trying to fit a LASSO regularized logistic regression model on a data set with the following structure:

- Response variable;
- Numeric covariates;
- Date covariate.

Since the numeric covariates are on different scales I'm thinking to scale them so that the penalty is evenly applied. Assuming this approach is correct for the numerical covariates, how should I be treating the date covariate?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use "days since XXX" for the date variable, where XXX is either the earliest date or some arbitrary date such as Jan 1, 1950.

Comment: Thanks @peter. What would be the implications of treating it as a categorical variable?

Comment: Treating it as categorical is almost certainly a mistake. It increases type 1 and type 2 error and introduces a sort of "magical thinking" where something magical happens at the cutoff.